Flet Container with icon and TextButton

How can I change a distance between two containers?
How can I combine icon and text button in one container so that when
I hover over the container, it appears as one unit?

Code I used:
ft.Text("Главная страница"),
            ft.Container(
                width=100,
                height=50,
                content=ft.Row([
                    ft.Image('assets/settings-icon.png', width=24, height=24),
                    ft.TextButton(text='Настройки', on_click=lambda _: navigate_to("/settings"))
                ])
            ),
            ft.Container(
                        width=100,
                        height=50,
                        content=ft.Row([
                            ft.Image('assets/info-icon.png', width=24, height=24),
                            ft.TextButton(text='Информация', on_click=lambda _: navigate_to("/info"))
                        ])
                        )

First problem
Second problem
I tried using Image and Button without a container and idk how to solve the problems

Flet Containers can take a margin argument, and you can pass in a Margin to set the spacing between the two containers
Can you talk more about your second question? What's the current behavior and what are you trying to accomplish?
